# How to make a backup of a pharo image

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

What is the recommended way to make a backup of a pharo 3.0 image on linux? I do not need anything too fancy, just a single backup.

I will be upgrading to pharo 4 soon; is there anything different I need to do on that version?

Thank you.

Comment: "Different" w.r.t. what? Making a back up? In that case: no, saving / backup will work exactly the same way as in Pharo 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to copy the .image and .changes files.  As long as they're kept together and have the same root name, you should be good to go.

Alternatively, if you choose "Save As.." from the world menu, you can create a backup copy of both files with a new name.  (Though that will change the name the currently running instance uses, so if you were just backing up, you'd want to exit immediately after doing that).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to backup code I use in github repos, this make the code way more modular for moving around images. Even in the case of moving from Pharo 3 to Pharo 4 or even Pharo 5. Of course you could achieve the same using StHub. To make things even easier you can make the code install with a single click via Configuration Browser.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the responses above - If your code is defined within your own packages then from the system browser you can File out and or commit in a repository - that way you will find it easier to import in your Pharo 4 image